# Calcular tempo online com JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, localstorage

Preciso desenvolver um código onde não tenho acesso a linguagens *back-end*, preciso fazer uma função que calcula o tempo que um usuário está online na página e salvar este tempo em *localStorage*, eu pensei em usar um `setInterval` a cada 1 segundo para atualizar o tempo que ele está *online*. E então atualizar o valor no storage, porém não sei trabalhar com tempo em Javascript/jQuery. Como eu poderia fazer isso?

Comment: É necessário saber os segundos?

Comment: É necessário sim amigo, não conheço o atributo Date muito bem, mas suponho que se não usarmos segundos ele vai fazer a atualização do tempo a cada 1 minuto certo? Mas digamos que o usuário atualize a página antes de completar 1 minuto? Ai eu acabaria perdendo todo esse tempo que se passou..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aqui fica uma sugestão:

Usar o evento `domready` para registar os milisegundos (timestamp) quando a página carregou. Depois usa o evento `beforeunload` para correr codigo exatamente antes da página fechar. Também é possível jogar com o `focus`no caso de se querer saber quando a página está em focus, ou o utilizador não está a ver essa página (sem focus).

código:

```
var aberturaPagina;
$(window).ready(function () {
    aberturaPagina = new Date().getTime();
});
$(window).on('beforeunload', function () {
    var fechoPagina = new Date().getTime();
    var tempoAberto = (fechoPagina - aberturaPagina) / 1000;

    // faxer qualquer coisa antes de fechar

});
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/8eCe9/)

No meu exemplo abre-se uma nova janela para mostrar os segundos. Desbloqueie os pop-ups para poder ver o resultado. Esse código é um exemplo. Você talvez queira fazer uma chamada AJAX para registar na base de dados.

Comment: cara gostei do seu código, como eu jogo esse valor para um banco de dados? Tipo usuário tempo? Podes me ajudar